# Find a column name from all tables and all databases with specified column name SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have several databases and I want to find a column name from my all databases with all tables.

This query gives me only list of all tables from just one database but I want all databases name with all tables name

```
SELECT 
    t.name,c.name 
FROM 
    sys.tables t 
INNER JOIN 
    sys.columns c  ON c.object_id = t.object_id 
WHERE 
    c.name LIKE '%CUSTOMERID%'
```

Thanks

Comment: I would employ Bash, or some other programming/scripting language for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are times when sp_foreachdb will just skip databases. Remember that it is an undocumented system procedure and as such there may be bugs in it. For something like this I prefer to just some dynamic sql. It isn't much more code than the undocumented cursor but it is more accurate.

```
declare @SQL nvarchar(max) = ''

select @SQL = @SQL + 'SELECT ''' + d.name + ''' as DatabaseName, t.name as TableName, c.name as ColumnName FROM ' + d.name + '.sys.tables t inner join ' + d.name + '.sys.columns c  ON c.object_id = t.object_id WHERE c.name LIKE ''%CUSTOMERID%'' union all '
from sys.databases d
where d.name not in('master', 'tempdb', 'msdb', 'model', 'ReportServer', 'ReportServerTempDB')

set @SQL = left(@SQL, len(@SQL) - 10)

exec sp_executesql @SQL
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
exec sp_msforeachdb
```

Example:

```
exec sp_msforeachdb 'use ? select top 10 * from sys.tables'
```

It basically executes a dynamic sql statement on each database. the '?' character is replaced with the current database it's iterating through. Use with care.

Comment: Thanks, but this query gives me some other results.